# ExoPlayer PlayerView is expanding in width on setting the `resizeMode` while the layout is constrained to use only 50% of the screen

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, exoplayer

Please refer to the attached image to understand the situation better.

When I am using a PlayerView for my implementation in a fragment that is set in landscape mode. I have constrained the PlayerView to 50% of screen using Guidelines in ConstraintLayout. The view that I have in the right half of this landscape is the CameraX `PreviewView`

But when I initialise the player(whether in xml or in Kotlin code) and set the resizeMode as

```
        playerView.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_HEIGHT
```

the PlayerView suddenly flow beyond the 50% constraint out into another view area as you see in the image attached. This is happening only when I am setting the `resizeMode` on the PlayerView

here is what all I already tried that still didnt change the problem I am facing.

1. Setting `PlayerView` in xml or in Kotlin
2. Using elevation and translateZ after the PlayerView is initialised and playing
3. Switching the position of PlayerView and PreviewView
4. Overlap the Camera PreviewView over PlayerView and vice-versa
5. Set size on after initialisation of PlayerView
6. Using relative layout to fix the 2 views, camera preview view and the PlayerView with 50/50 distribution on the screen

[image]